# How to create a div that will be fixed when I scroll the container horizontally, without overflowing the container vertically?

Tags: html, css, r, shiny, shinydashboard

Unfortunately I could not create a reproducible example in HTML, because the app I am developing is a shiny application in R language, but the problem I am having is with the html/css part.

In the image below, I have the div highlighted with the blue box that contains a table (using rHandsonTable), I need to make it fixed when I scroll horizontally, but when I use the fixed position it overflows the container. The other tables are all inside divs as well:
[image: issue]

Here is a reproducible example in R with shiny:

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)

data <- data.frame(
  COL_A = rep('A', 29),COL_B = rep('B', 29),COL_C = rep('C', 29),COL_D = rep(9999, 29),
  COL_E = rep(9999 , 29),COL_F = rep(9999, 29),COL_G = rep(9999, 29),COL_H = rep(9999, 29),
  COL_I = rep(9999, 29),COL_J = rep(9999, 29),COL_K = rep(9999, 29),COL_L = rep(9999, 29),
  COL_M = rep(9999, 29),COL_N = rep(9999, 29),COL_O = rep(9999, 29),COL_P = rep(9999, 29),
  COL_Q = rep(9999, 29),COL_R = rep(9999, 29),COL_S = rep(9999, 29),COL_T = rep(9999, 29),
  COL_U = rep(9999, 29),COL_V = rep(9999, 29),COL_X = rep(9999, 29),COL_Y = rep(9999, 29),
  COL_Z = rep(9999, 29)
)

dsHead <- dashboardHeader(title='Example', titleWidth = '100%')

dsSideBar <- dashboardSidebar(disable = TRUE)

dsBody <- dashboardBody(
  box(width = 12, 
      div(style = 'overflow-x:scroll; overflow-y: auto', class = 'hot_semborda',
          div(style='white-space:nowrap;height:400px',
              div(style='display: inline-block;padding-left: 200px;position:fixed',
                  rHandsontableOutput('hot_abs')),
              div(style='display: inline-block;padding-left: 200px;',
                  rHandsontableOutput('hot_imp')),
              div(style='display: inline-block;padding-left: 200px;',
                  rHandsontableOutput('hot_ent')),
              div(style='display: inline-block;padding-left: 200px;',
                  rHandsontableOutput('hot_transf')),
              div(style='display: inline-block;padding-left: 200px;',
                  rHandsontableOutput('hot_vda')),
              div(style='display: inline-block;padding-left: 200px;',
                  rHandsontableOutput('hot_pes')))
      )
  )
)

ui <- dashboardPage(dsHead, dsSideBar, dsBody)

server <- function(input,output,session) {
  output$hot_abs <- renderRHandsontable(
    rhandsontable(data[,c('COL_A', 'COL_B', 'COL_C')])
  )

  output$hot_imp <- renderRHandsontable(
    rhandsontable(data[,c('COL_D', 'COL_E', 'COL_F', 'COL_G', 'COL_H')])
  )

  output$hot_ent <- renderRHandsontable(
    rhandsontable(data[,c('COL_K', 'COL_L', 'COL_M', 'COL_N', 'COL_O')])
  )

  output$hot_transf <- renderRHandsontable(
    rhandsontable(data[,c('COL_P', 'COL_Q', 'COL_R', 'COL_S', 'COL_T')])
  )

  output$hot_vda <- renderRHandsontable(
    rhandsontable(data[,c('COL_U', 'COL_V', 'COL_X')])
  )

  output$hot_pes<- renderRHandsontable(
    rhandsontable(data[,c('COL_Y', 'COL_Z')])
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: try using overflow-y: scroll on your parent container of the bluebox. Here is a link to other ways to use overflow-y - https://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/css3_pr_overflow-y.asp

Comment: Didn't work, the container still overflows the parent box.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use two boxes placing them appropriately. Since you want your columns A, B,C to be always displayed on the left, maybe you could use one small box A, B, C and another one for the remaining columns.

Generally, from what I understand, adding HTML tags applies changes on the whole page and not separately on each shiny element. So probably it ignores totally the limits of the box.

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)

data <- data.frame(
  COL_A = rep('A', 29),COL_B = rep('B', 29),COL_C = rep('C', 29),COL_D = rep(9999, 29),
  COL_E = rep(9999 , 29),COL_F = rep(9999, 29),COL_G = rep(9999, 29),COL_H = rep(9999, 29),
  COL_I = rep(9999, 29),COL_J = rep(9999, 29),COL_K = rep(9999, 29),COL_L = rep(9999, 29),
  COL_M = rep(9999, 29),COL_N = rep(9999, 29),COL_O = rep(9999, 29),COL_P = rep(9999, 29),
  COL_Q = rep(9999, 29),COL_R = rep(9999, 29),COL_S = rep(9999, 29),COL_T = rep(9999, 29),
  COL_U = rep(9999, 29),COL_V = rep(9999, 29),COL_X = rep(9999, 29),COL_Y = rep(9999, 29),
  COL_Z = rep(9999, 29)
)

dsHead <- dashboardHeader(title='Example', titleWidth = '100%')

dsSideBar <- dashboardSidebar(disable = TRUE)

dsBody <- dashboardBody(
  box(width = 2,
      div(style = 'overflow-x:scroll; overflow-y: auto', class = 'hot_semborda',
          div(style='white-space:nowrap;height:400px',
              div(
                  rHandsontableOutput('hot_abs'))
          )
      )
  ),
  box(width = 10, 
      div(style = 'overflow-x:scroll; overflow-y: auto', class = 'hot_semborda',
          div(style='white-space:nowrap;height:400px',
              div(style='display: inline-block;padding-left: 200px;',
                  rHandsontableOutput('hot_imp')),
              div(style='display: inline-block;padding-left: 200px;',
                  rHandsontableOutput('hot_ent')),
              div(style='display: inline-block;padding-left: 200px;',
                  rHandsontableOutput('hot_transf')),
              div(style='display: inline-block;padding-left: 200px;',
                  rHandsontableOutput('hot_vda')),
              div(style='display: inline-block;padding-left: 200px;',
                  rHandsontableOutput('hot_pes')))
      )
  )
)

ui <- dashboardPage(dsHead, dsSideBar, dsBody)

server <- function(input,output,session) {
  output$hot_abs <- renderRHandsontable(
    rhandsontable(data[,c('COL_A', 'COL_B', 'COL_C')])
  )

  output$hot_imp <- renderRHandsontable(
    rhandsontable(data[,c('COL_D', 'COL_E', 'COL_F', 'COL_G', 'COL_H')])
  )

  output$hot_ent <- renderRHandsontable(
    rhandsontable(data[,c('COL_K', 'COL_L', 'COL_M', 'COL_N', 'COL_O')])
  )

  output$hot_transf <- renderRHandsontable(
    rhandsontable(data[,c('COL_P', 'COL_Q', 'COL_R', 'COL_S', 'COL_T')])
  )

  output$hot_vda <- renderRHandsontable(
    rhandsontable(data[,c('COL_U', 'COL_V', 'COL_X')])
  )

  output$hot_pes<- renderRHandsontable(
    rhandsontable(data[,c('COL_Y', 'COL_Z')])
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```